# Parse a string to find and remove a float

Tags: python, string

I am created a pythod method that will take in a string of variable length, that will always include a floating point number at the end :

```
"adsfasdflkdslf:asldfasf-adslfk:1.5698464586546"
```

OR

```
"asdif adfi=9393 adfkdsf:1.84938"
```

I need to parse the string and return the floating point number at the end. There usually a delimiter character before the float, such as : - or a space.

```
def findFloat(stringArg):
    stringArg.rstrip()
    stringArg.replace("-",":")

    if stringArg.rfind(":"):
        locateFloat = stringArg.rsplit(":")

    #second element should be the desired float
    magicFloat = locateFloat[1]
    return magicFloat
```

I am recieving a

> magicFloat = locateFloat[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Any guidence on how to locate the float and return it would be awesome.

Comment: Step 1: use `rpartition()` method for this.  Step 2, include the actual input string that's giving you the error message.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the number is negative? Replacing '-' delimiters might not be such a good idea. Where is this data coming from that the format is defined so weakly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Python, strings are immutable. No matter what function you call on a string, the actual text of that string does not change. Thus, methods like `rstrip`, `replace` etc. create a **new** string representing the modified version. (You would know this if you read the documentation.) In your code, you do not assign the results of these calls anywhere in the first two statements, so the results are lost.
2. Without specifying a number of splits, `rsplit` does the exact same thing that `split` does. It checks for splits from the end, sure, but it still splits at every possible point, so the net effect is the same. You need to specify that you want to split at most one time.
3. However, you shouldn't do that anyway; a much simpler way to get "everything after the last colon, or everything if there is no colon" is to use `rpartition`.
4. You don't actually have to remove whitespace from the end for `float` conversion. Although you probably should actually, you know, perform the conversion.
5. Finally, there is no point in assigning to a variable just to return it; just return the expression directly.

Putting that together gives us the exceptionally simple:

```
def findFloat(stringArg):
    return float(stringArg.replace('-', ':').rpartition(':')[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

re always rocks.  Depending on what your floating point number looks like (leading 0?) something like:

```
magicFloat = re.search('.*([0-9]\.[0-9]+)',st).group(1)
```

p.s. if you do this a lot, precompile the regex first:

```
re_float = re.compile('.*([0-9]\.[0-9]+)')
# later in your code
magicFloat = re_float.search(st).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in an easier manner:

```
def findFloat(stringArg):
    s = stringArg.rstrip()
    return s.split('-:')[-1]
```

1. *rstrip() will return the stripped string, you must store it somewhere*
2. *split() can take multiple token, you can avoid the replace then*
3. *rsplit() is an optimization, but split()[-1] will always take the latest element in the split list*
4. *locateFloat is not defined if no rfind() is found*
5. *in you need to find a char, you could write `if ':' in stringArg:` instead.*

Hope thoses tips would help you later :)

Comment: The OP also said that "there's **usually** a delimiter character" and that character could be a `:` `-` or a space *(from my understanding)*.

Comment: Hello Comrades, the main thing is that the float is always at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
>>> st = "adsfasdflkdslf:asldfasf-adslfk:1.5698464586546"
>>> float(re.split(r':|\s|-',st)[-1])
1.5698464586545999
```

I have used [re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) which split string by the occurrences of pattern.

Here pattern is your delimiter like `:,white-space(\s),-`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always at the end you should use `$` in your re:

```
import re
def findFloat(stringArg):
    fl = re.search(r'([\.0-9]+)$', stringArg)
    return fl and float(fl.group(1))
```